# web.config not being generated for migrated (project.json -> .csproj) asp.net core application

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, web-config, visual-studio-2017

### Background

We have an ASP.NET Core application that, on every push/merge into *master* on githup, is built and deployed to a development slot on an App Service in Azure. This application was built with Visual Studio Code using a project.json file. We recently migrated it to Visual Studio 2017 (using `dotnet migrate`). The migration kept our web.config file as it was, and migrated our pre-publish scripts to the .csproj file, but did not bring over the post-publish script that ran `dotnet publish-iis`. Because of this the web.config file was not being updated to replace the `%LAUNCHER_*%` placeholders with values relevant to the Azure deployment.

To figure out how the web.config is supposed to look in this new .csproj world, we created a brand-new dotnet project (using Visual Studio 2017, not `dotnet new`) to look at the web.config, but it did not actually create on with the project. However, one magically appears in the web root on the server after deployment.

We tried getting rid of our web.config, but it did not cause it to be generated. We compared everything in our project with the new one and could not find anything that looks like it is either triggering it (in the new proj) or preventing it (in our old one). We have searched all over the web for what triggers the web.config to be automatically generated but found nothing.

### Where We Currently Are

We realize we can replace the `%LAUNCHER_*%` placeholders with actual values and get it to work, but it would be preferred if we could get our project to magically generate the web.config like the newly created projects do.

### The Ask

Thus our question is, how can we cause the web.config to be generated on build or deployment like a newly created project does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web.config generation is part of the "Web SDK" that the csproj project uses. If the project file starts with

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

it will automatically get the web.config transformation logic. The `dotnet publish-iis` step is no longer necessary. If you did not directly include any asp.net core nuget packages in the project, the migration might have failed to notice that your project is actually a web project (or there may be a bug).

Another setting that can suppress the web.config is

```
<IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
```

inside the csproj file.

Comment: Damn! We looked at that when comparing the files, but "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" looks a lot like "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web", especially after staring at so many other things of the previous few hours. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't want to generate web.config, so adding `IsTransformWebConfigDisabled` helped with that